# How to update the deployment of nodejs app without terminating the existing connections

Tags: node.js, nginx, pm2

**nginx** is used as the reverse proxy in a server which runs a nodejs app. **pm2** node module is used to launch the app. When a new version of the nodejs app has to be deployed, i would like to launch a new instance of the latest node app and all the new incoming requests should be served by this new nodejs app instance.

The old nodejs app instance should exit once all the existing requests (i.e connected before the new  nodejs app is launched) are disconnected.

How to get this kind of setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run your node.js server as a cluster with pm2 `pm2 start app.js -i max`. And when the new code is checked out simply run `pm2 reload all`and it will reload your app with 0s downtime.

How it works?

It launches new workers with your new code running and tells your old workers to stop listening to new connections and shut down themselves when they finish serving their current requests if any.

Comment: I'm using pm2 reload in my app but in my test the active requests are cancelled by the reload. I tested by making an await of 10 seconds, requesting a response to the respective route with Insomnia and then, before the 10 seconds complete, reloading the app with pm2. But what happens is that the pm2 reload stops the Insomnia request, which finishes as "Error: Server returned nothing (no headers, no data)". Am I doing something wrong? Was not pm2 supposed to identify current running requests on await state?